# How can I read data file using for loop separated by spaces?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am new in bash scripting and trying to solve one problem for my data file.

I have a file that has three columns, the pattern of the file is as follows

```
#col1   #col2   #col3  

1.1 0.0 2.1
1.2 0.0 2.2
1.3 0.0 2.3

0.9 0.0 0.3
0.8 0.0 0.4
0.7 0.0 0.4

2.1 0.0 0.6
2.1 0.0 0.6
2.2 0.0 0.7
```

and it has more than 1000 terms.

I have to take the average of the third column. For this, I have to read the file in one loop and then consider the space, and do the same for the second loop, consider the space, and then loop for the third column.

I wrote a small script but I am not able to understand how I can start the second iteration again and calculate the average.

```
IFS=$'\n'
count=0;
total=0;
for i in $( awk '{print $3;}' Berry_Ef)
do
        k=$(awk -v n=$i 'NR==n{print $3}' )
        total=$( echo $total+$i | bc)
        ((count ++))
done
echo "$count" "count">> sum
echo  "$total" "total">>sum
echo "scale=5; $total/$count" | bc >>sum
```

Any suggestion and help matter to me.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: It looks like your file has more than three columns (nine in your example), but three rows (aka lines). What are you calling a "column", a "term", and for that matter "norm"?

Comment: @GordonDavisson That was due to formatting; not marking as a code block swallowed the linebreaks.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but still unclear. Do you mean `average` by `norm`? Do you mean `a blank line` by `the space`? It will be clearer if you can update the question with your expected output using the shown input. BR.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I want to calculate the average. and space means a blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting to use single `awk` script to read and process input file only once.

```
 awk ' { 
   ++col3Count;
   total = total + $3;
 }
 END {
   printf("total = %d count = %d normal = %d\n", total, col3Count, (total/col3Count));
 }
 ' input.csv
```